# How to Separate a string (Arabic string)

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a combined string that I want to separate.

**My Pattern:** (*Arabic language, Starts from the right )*:

```
str3[str2](str1)
```

---

**Example 1**

For the input:

> string = تَ) [ ع . ] (مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن)

I want the output:

```
$str1='(تَ)';
$str2='[ ع . ]';
$str3='مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن)';
```

---

**Example 2**

For the input:

> string = اِ تَ) (مص ل .) = اباته : شب را در جایی گذراندن)

I want the output:

```
$str1='(اِ تَ)';
$str2='';
$str3='مص ل .) = اباته : شب را در جایی گذراندن)';
```

---

**Example 3**

For the input:

> string =  [ ع . ] (مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن

I want the output:

```
$str1='';
$str2='[ ع . ]';
$str3='(مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن';
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's Persian, Not Arabic!

Comment: @someOne you right, but i siad Arabic because i  thought it is more common.

Comment: Meh. I know how to do it but my computer and Persian language don't see eye to eye it appears xD

Comment: @icecub The difficult part is the Right-to-left nature.

Comment: @icecub: I thought I did too, but the RTL aspect apparently complicates things. My solution *mostly* works, but "mostly" doesn't really cut it! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ghehe ye it really buggs me. Very interesting problem though. I'm wondering what the solution might be.

Comment: If there is the uniform sequence followed either seperation was followed by `()` or `[]` it would be easy If so The string 3 is expected to be (مص ل .) right ?

Comment: The string is just visually correct and **looks** right, but it is not, for example the `اِ تَ` is supposed to be enclosed in parenthesis, but it just looks to be! The correctly positioned expression should be `(اِ تَ) [ع. اباتة] (مص ل.) = اباته : شب را در جایی گذراندن`

Comment: There's something odd about the first example. The string seems to have more than one kind of `)` in it, like there's a LTR character buried in the middle of the RTL text. I can see it when I select the text, and if I copy a `(` from before that point and paste it (in isolation), it converts to `)`, but if I copy one *after* that point and pasted it, it pastes as `(`.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen string3 can be included anything. () or [] or {}.

Comment: Got it, the error is in the all the first open parenthesis, they have a LTR direction rather than a RTL one, so @Sajad can you confirm that the rest of the strings have the same characteristics? (or if you cant post some)

Comment: @Sajad : Ok, according to your words seperation can be done either by `()` or `[]` or `{}`. So the first seperation leads to `(تَ)` then `[ ع . اباتة ]` then `(مص ل .)` am i right ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen you right about first and second, but third is all the rest.

Comment: @Sajad : Ok, can you give the clue on how can i seperate the third one ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen the third has not a clue in fact, just i can say that the third is all that remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, the apparently first character (the rightmost) is not the open parenthesis as it supposed to be (in fact it's the last character),  and this hidden error causes misunderstandings (it's just visually correct). However, the following code corrects the error and outputs the desired strings.

```
<?php
$arrStr = [
'تَ) [ ع . ] (مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن)',
'اِ تَ) (مص ل .) = اباته : شب را در جایی گذراندن)',
];
echo "<body style='direction: rtl !important;'>";
foreach($arrStr as $str) {
    preg_match('~(.*?\))(?:\s)(\[.*?\])?(?:\s*?)(.*)~', $str, $matches);
    $matches[1] = "(".$matches[1];
    $matches[3] = trim(substr($matches[3], 0, -1));
    echo "<pre>";
    for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
        echo "$i: {$matches[$i]}<br />";
    echo "</pre><hr>";
}
echo "</body>";
?>
```

**The output:** *(Please note that the entries are in the correct RTL direction and will be displayed correctly on a RTL environment (they don't act falsify as being correct on a LTR environment.))*

```
1: (تَ)
2: [ ع . ]
3: (مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن
_____________________________________________
1: (اِ تَ)
2: 
3: (مص ل .) = اباته : شب را در جایی گذراندن
_____________________________________________
```

---

**P.S:** So, here is your new scenario: The first part enclosed in `()` is optional, the second part enclosed in `[]` is also optional, but the third part is mandatory; According to your examples above, the third part may also start with a `(*)`, Due to this, and considering the example of `B (A)` there is **NO** way to determine whether the example is in a format which has the optional first part `(A)` followed by the mandatory 3rd part `B`, or is in a format which doesn't have any of the optional parts but has the mandatory 3rd part being the whole string, if that's not a concern you may use the `~(.*?\)\s)?(\[.*?\]\s)?(.*)~` as the regular expression.

Comment: I have a questin, where is that in your code: `if str2 does not exist then $str2='';` ??

Comment: @Sajad That's in the `..(\[.*?\])?..` part of the regular expression.

Comment: I can never understand the regex language. can you tell me, if i want implement the same possibility for str1, what should i do ??

Comment: @Sajad Then you might change the beginning of the regex to `~(.*?\))?..`. Seriously, you're better to elaborate on the possibilities beforehand!!

Comment: No I just want to know it ...! anyway tnx pal ..!

Comment: Really ashamed that I ask the question again. I want to know, how can i define this via regex : `if (\(.*?\)) was the first of string` . can you tell me ?

Comment: thanks for your update, but `str1` is not optional (both in the new regex and old), in oder word, if `str1` does not exist,then `str1=str2` and `str2=''`. it is means that `str1` is never empty, Unless both `str1=''` and `str2=''`, then `str1` will be empty (and of course `str2`)

Comment: Please check out my new updated (example3). I know that I was so wrong that I did not mention to the conditions.

Comment: My problem was solved, You've really helped me. Tnx alot

Answer (score 2):

You can match on the unicode equivalents of the Arabic (also Farsi) characters.  Here is code which will match `(تَ)`:

```
$str = تَ) [ ع . ] (مص م .) راست کردن ، معتدل کردن);
preg_match('/^.*(\(\u064E\u062A\)).*$/iu', $str);
```

In the above expression `\u064E` is the vowel fetHa (which comes first) while `\u062A` is the consonant ta.  The `\u` flag tells PHP to operate in unicode mode.

Comment: Honestly, I think this would be the best solution of all. It's the same idea I was working on, but unfortunetely I was unable to get all the unicode equivalents because my pc simply refuses to work with all the characters (it starts replacing them with standard enUS characters).